# Reledmac/reledpar footnotes through two lines of verse issue an error

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

When I try to comment on two lines with a single footnote, I get an error, although the document compiles well. The error does not appear with prose text. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noledgroup,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
    \setstanzaindents{12,0}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}

First line text. \edtext{An interesting&
Phrase}{\Afootnote{A comment on two lines.}}. Second line text.\&

\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

Right-hand side...

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

And the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \no@expands An interesting&Phrase l.33 The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is false to said the problem happens with edtext on two lines, its happen with edtext on two lines of verse, which is not the same thing.

The reason would be too complex to explain. It is possible I think to solve it with astanza, but not with normal stanza. So I won't take time to solve it to with astanza.

However, reledmac provides tools to turn around.

- You must port your  edtext only on one line of verse, ideally the first one, as the footnote is inserted on the page which start the lemma.
- You must mark with edlabel the two part of your verse
- You must use `\xxref` referring to the labels to get correct line numbers on footnote
- You must use `\lemma` to get a correct lemma.

So see (as you can see on the  right page, the problem is NOT linked to two lines, but to two lines of verse)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noledgroup,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
    \setstanzaindents{12,0}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}

First line text. \edtext{An interesting}{%
  \lemma{An interesting Phrase}%
  \xxref{begin}{end}%
  \Afootnote{A comment on two lines.}%
}\edlabel{begin}&
\edlabel{end}Phrase. Second line text.\&

\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...\edtext{Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side}{\Afootnote{SNCF}}...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, there was no problem with prose. I said it in the question, but now I made the title more precise. 
The workaround works, thank you very much!

Comment: However, there is another little point. When I use this strategy for endnotes, having more than one endnote, line numbers get mixed-up. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It is maybe a bug (maybe not), but without MWE I can't tell you.

Comment: Ok, I opened a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397837/reledmac-reledpar-problem-with-endnote-verse-line-numbers-referring-to-multiple).

Comment: That was not a bug but a misuse, see my answer.