# Reledmac/reledpar: problem with endnote verse line numbers referring to multiple lines

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

The question is related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397767/reledmac-reledpar-footnotes-through-two-lines-of-verse-issue-an-error). The problem of the error  with footnotes referring to multiple verse lines is resolved by a workaround, but when several endnotes are used, line numbers do not seem to be correct, even after several runs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noledgroup,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
    \setstanzaindents{12,0}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}

First line text. \edtext{An interesting}{%
  \lemma{An interesting Phrase}%
  \xxref{begin}{end}%
  \Aendnote{Comment on lines 1-2.}%
}\edlabel{begin}&
\edlabel{end}Phrase. Second line text.&
Third line text. \edtext{An interesting}{%
  \lemma{An interesting Phrase}%
  \xxref{begin}{end}%
  \Aendnote{Comment on lines 3-4.}%
}\edlabel{begin}&
\edlabel{end}Phrase. Fourth line text.\&

\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...\edtext{Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side}{\Afootnote{SNCF}}...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\doendnotes{A}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't understand how to use `\xxref`.
If you change endnote to footnote, you see you get the same problem :)

`\xxref` is used to change line number in foot/endnote. The first argument is the name of a label placed on the first line, the second argument is the name of a label placed on the last line.

You have placed two times a `begin` label and a `\end` label. So only the last one of the two is used to determine line number.

Both reledmac and LaTeX told you that you have a problem with yours label. In the compilation message/log file, you can read

```
Package reledmac Warning: Duplicate definition of label `begin'.


LaTeX Warning: Label `begin' multiply defined.


Package reledmac Warning: Duplicate definition of label `end'.


LaTeX Warning: Label `end' multiply defined.
```

Here a example which will get you the good result

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[series={A},noledgroup,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
    \setstanzaindents{12,0}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}

First line text. \edtext{An interesting}{%
  \lemma{An interesting Phrase}%
  \xxref{begin1}{end1}%
  \Aendnote{Comment on lines 1-2.}%
}\edlabel{begin1}&
\edlabel{end1}Phrase. Second line text.&
Third line text. \edtext{An interesting}{%
  \lemma{An interesting Phrase}%
  \xxref{begin2}{end2}%
  \Aendnote{Comment on lines 3-4.}%
}\edlabel{begin2}&
\edlabel{end2}Phrase. Fourth line text.\&

\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...\edtext{Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side}{\Afootnote{SNCF}}...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...Right-hand side...

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\doendnotes{A}

\end{document}
```

May I suggest you to use [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) :

- As reledmac/reledpar can need many run, you will be sur to runs the good number of time.
- At the end of latexmk, you get a summary of the label problem (and also of some other potential problem, for example citekey problems)

Comment: Exactly; I expected a sort of counter reset after each use. Many thanks!

Comment: It won't be possible, as you may have edtext referring to overlapping lemma.